# walk must return same type as input?

Tags: hy

I'm unclear on how the `outer` function provided to `walk` should work.

The example in documentation referenced here:
https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/contrib/walk.html

Suggests the `outer` function can be `first` which would return the first element of the collection produced by mapping over with `inner`.

However when I try to aggregate the result in `outer` (eg `sum` or `first`) I get an error as per below - complaining that `int` is not iterable - looking at the source code I suspect this is because of `(type form)` in the macro definition:

`((type form) (outer (HyExpression (map inner form))))`

Can anyone confirm, and advise if there is a way of having `outer` return a different type to the input `form`?  i.e. can `(walk inc sum [1 2 3 4 5])` be made to provide the sum of the list `[2 3 4 5 6]` as I'd expect?

```
=> (walk inc identity [1 2 3 4 5])
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
=> (walk inc accumulate [1 2 3 4 5])
[2, 5, 9, 14, 20]
=> (walk inc sum [1 2 3 4 5])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin-75eb4a20707c49e8c921e986e7d6164d36b7e4b2", line 1, in <module>
    (walk inc sum [1 2 3 4 5])
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hy/contrib/walk.hy", line 22, in walk
    ((type form) (outer (HyExpression (map inner form))))]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
=> (walk inc first [1 2 3 4 5])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin-710dcc990bf071fe1a9a4c5501831c41867f1879", line 1, in <module>
    (walk inc first [1 2 3 4 5])
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hy/contrib/walk.hy", line 22, in walk
    ((type form) (outer (HyExpression (map inner form))))]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
=>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's a bug.](https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/1854) Say `(sum (map inc [1 2 3 4 5]))` instead.